# Flash Performance on Ubuntu

Tags: laptop, ubuntu-9.04

I just reformatted my laptop and installed Ubuntu 9.04. Everything is working great except Flash.

YouTube videos play but are horrible quality and choppy (was fine when Vista was installed) and I can't click Flash hyperlinks.

I am currently using Firefox 3.5.4, the lastest version of Flash 10, and flashplugin-nonfree.

Is there anything I can do to make Flash work better? Unfortunately, if not, this is a deal breaker for me. I really would like to use Ubuntu.

UPDATE: My laptop specs are

AMD Turion X2 2.0 Ghz CPU,
4 GB RAM,
ATI X1270 graphics

Comment: I don't think this belongs here, it's not exactly a server issue. More suitable for SuperUser. See the FAQ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually more related to your video card and drivers.

I had similar horrible flash performance with an ATI card on Ubuntu. Basically I switched it out for a Nvidia card as the drivers are much better.  Of course, it's not so easy on a laptop unfortunately. But from what I understand ATI drivers are garbage for linux.  Sorry that's not really any help I suppose.

But I'd complain more to ATI

Answer (score 2):

Wait for 9.10 to be released and upgrade. There are significant performance upgrades for flash video on intel based video chipsets.

I've upgraded to the beta release of 9.10 and have had a much better viewing experience with full screen youtube and abc iview flash videos.

Comment: I forgot to mention my laptop has a Turion X2 CPU. Will 9.10 have improvements for AMD processors?

Comment: Yes the will be improvements.

Answer (score 1):

- try gnash
- ask ubuntuforums.org or superuser.com
- complain to adobe